# Is there a better way to make this code thread-safe? Thread_local static seems a blunt tool

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

The following code mimics a larger programme that creates an instance of a simulation and then parallelises it using `firstprivate` to make my instances private. However, the instance itself creates two more instances within its methods.

The structure seems contrived but my hands are tied somewhat: the classes and their dependence are dictated to me by the tools I would like to use and I think this scenario is common in the scientific computing community.

It compiles fine and upon manual testing appears to be thread-safe and working.

But I am not sure I am using C++ technology in an optimal way as I suspect I could declare instances further up in the memory hierarchy and save myself from having to use a `static` variable, possibly via passing an instance created in a `parallel` region by reference to my other instance or something like that. I suspect this is best because everything within the braces of `#pragma omp parallel {}` is local to the thread.

Hence, my goal is to create two (or more) thread-local, independent instances of each class, and in particular GenNo as it models a random number generator that is to be seeded once per thread and then simply called with the same seed although here I am changing what I call the 'seed' in a predictable way just to understand the programme's behaviour and reveal violations of thread safety / race conditions.

The code that is commented out did not work but produced a 'segmentation fault' with the programme exiting with `SIGSEGV 11.` I believe that the 'unique' pointer is not so unique when deployed in parallel. Overall, this solution seems more elegant though and I would like to make it work but am happy to listen to your comments.

In order to get the `std::unique_ptr` functionality, the line beginning with `thread_local static` has to be commented out and the other comments have to be removed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>
//#include <memory>

class GenNo
{
public:

    int num;

    explicit GenNo(int num_)
    {
        num = num_;
    };

    void create(int incr)
    {
        num += incr;
    }
};

class HelpCrunch{
public:
    HelpCrunch() {

    }

    void helper(int number)
    {
        std::cout << "Seed is " << number << " for thread number: " << omp_get_thread_num() << std::endl;
    }
};

class calculate : public HelpCrunch
{
public:

    int specific_seed;
    bool first_run;

    void CrunchManyNos()
    {
        HelpCrunch solver;

        thread_local static GenNo RanNo(specific_seed);
        //std::unique_ptr<GenNo> GenNo_ptr(nullptr);
        /*
        if(first_run == true)
        {
            GenNo_ptr.reset(new GenNo(specific_seed));
            first_run = false;
        }
         solver.helper(GenNo_ptr->num);
*/
        RanNo.create(1);
        solver.helper(RanNo.num);



        //do actual things that I hope are useful.
    };
};




int main()
{

    calculate MyLargeProb;
    MyLargeProb.first_run = true;

#pragma omp parallel firstprivate(MyLargeProb)
    {
        int thread_specific_seed = omp_get_thread_num();
        MyLargeProb.specific_seed = thread_specific_seed;

        #pragma omp for
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            MyLargeProb.CrunchManyNos();
            std::cout << "Current iteration is " << i << std::endl;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now the output with the `thread_local static` keyword was:

```
Seed is 2 for thread number: 1
Current iteration is 5
Seed is 3 for thread number: 1
Current iteration is 6
Seed is 4 for thread number: 1
Current iteration is 7
Seed is 5 for thread number: 1
Current iteration is 8
Seed is 6 for thread number: 1
Current iteration is 9


Seed is 1 for thread number: 0
Current iteration is 0
Seed is 2 for thread number: 0
Current iteration is 1
Seed is 3 for thread number: 0
Current iteration is 2
Seed is 4 for thread number: 0
Current iteration is 3
Seed is 5 for thread number: 0
Current iteration is 4
```

While without using `thread_local` but retaining `static` I get:

```
Seed is 2 for thread number: 1
Current iteration is 5
Seed is 3 for thread number: 1
Current iteration is 6
Seed is 4 for thread number: 1
Current iteration is 7
Seed is 6 for thread number: 1
Current iteration is 8
Seed is 7 for thread number: 1
Current iteration is 9


Seed is 5 for thread number: 0
Current iteration is 0
Seed is 8 for thread number: 0
Current iteration is 1
Seed is 9 for thread number: 0
Current iteration is 2
Seed is 10 for thread number: 0
Current iteration is 3
Seed is 11 for thread number: 0
Current iteration is 4
```

If I leave out the `static` keyword altogether, the instance just keeps getting re-assigned and while I strongly suspect it would be kept private to the thread, it is of little use as the counter would be stuck at 1 or 2 for thread 0 and 1 on a dual core machine. (The real-world application would have to be able to 'count up' and be undisturbed by the parallel thread.)

### What I need help with

Now, I modeled the example in way that a violation of thread safety would become apparent via the counters interfering with each other, as we can see is the case when thread_local is left out but static is left in (having neither is silly). The class `HelpCrunch` is in reality much more complex and most likely thread-safe and fine to be reinitialised with each loop repetition. (This is actually better because it picks up a bunch of variables from its child that is a private instance.) But do you think I would be better off adding thread_local to the creation of `solver` as well, without the `static` keyword? Or should I declare the instance elsewhere, in which case I would need help with the passing by pointer/reference etc.

Comment: Why not simply create a generator for each thread and store them in a vector (just make sure they are stored far enough apart in memory)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your example uses the global object `std::cout` in a thread-unsafe way, accessing it concurrently from multiple threads. I had to add `#pragma omp critical` at some places to get a readable output.

Second, the commented code crashes because `GenNo_ptr` has automatic duration so that it is destroyed every time `CrunchManyNos()` completes execution. Therefore, when `first_run` is `false` you are derefencing a `nullptr` pointer.

When it comes to your specific question, there is a huge difference between making `RanNo` `static` or `static thread_local`:

- If it is `static` there will be a single instance of `RanNo`
  initialized the first time `CrunchManyNos()` gets executed. It is to
  some extent a global variable that would be used unsafely in the
  concurrent context of your example.
- If it is `static thread_local`  (by the way using openmp you should prefer `threadprivate`) it will
  be created the first time a new thread calls `CrunchManyNos()` and
  will last for the duration of the thread.

Comment: thanks a lot! Do you see a way of using the pointer to avoid its being disposed of? Also, where did you add the critical statements? The output was more for seeing how the programme runs. About static Vs the pointers, which way is better in terms of style?

Comment: @Hirek Smart pointers allow working with them as if they were automatic variables. Therefore, `static thread_local std::unique_ptr<GenNo> GenNo_ptr` would work. However, there is no point in using dynamic allocation in this case.

Comment: @Hirek I guarded every use of `std::cout` with `#pragma omp critical` for your example to work. But do not use it in real code unless it is absolutely necessary as that thread synchronization will kill performance.

Comment: @Hirek Your code look suspicious to me because most of your variables depend either directly or indirectly on the thread id, though I don’t know your use case and I can theoretically only comment here on things that are not working in your code. Otherwise it’s [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) material.

Comment: yes I can see that. The use case is much bigger and I know that using thread id for parallel random number generation is clunky and not as good as using some Unix random device to set the seed

Comment: but this meant to be reproducible while maintaining statistical independence.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186518/discussion-between-hirek-and-metalfox).